# LatencyAwarePolicy datastax cassandra version 4.6 and connect without local datacenter

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am moving my project to spring boot 2.3.5 which has driver 4.6 and LatencyAwarePolicy looks like disappeared from existence. I wonder do we have similar policy builder for driver 4.6 or what is the best approach for 4.6.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/LatencyAwarePolicy.Builder.html

I search but could not find anything in the docs. maybe https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/loadbalancing/BasicLoadBalancingPolicy.java
with BasicLoadBalancingPolicy I can connect without data center name but I am confused is this as good as LatencyAwarePolicy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default load balancing policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/load_balancing/#default-policy) in 4.x now has best practices baked in, including token awareness and busy node avoidance (which was the goal of LatencyAware).

This blog post discusses more:
https://www.datastax.com/blog/improved-client-request-routing-apache-cassandratm

You can still implement any LBP you care to by implementing the [LoadBalancingPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.9/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/loadbalancing/LoadBalancingPolicy.html) interface, but it normally should not be necessary.

Comment: default did not allow me to connect without local data center name, but with my old code I had LatencyAwarePolicy and did not give any datacentername. for 4.x how should I connect ?

Comment: If explicit contact points are provided (i.e. not just default localhost), when a datacenter must also be provided, either in the configuration, or programmatically with a builder. It's explained a littler further down in the manual section I linked.